# Iterating over Immutable JS Map

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

Consider this code:

```
const map1 = Immutable.Map({a:1, b:2, c:3});

const myMap = map1.map((elem, index) => {
    return "Hello " + elem;
})

console.log(myMap.toJS());
// prnts {a: "Hello 1", b: "Hello 2", c: "Hello 3"}
```

I want the output as `['Hello1', 'Hello2, 'Hello3']`, but `map` is giving me an object with the keys also. Why am I not getting an array as output like a normal JavaScript `map` works? And what is the best way to achieve the desired result? (I can use `forEach` instead of `map`, and push the result of each iteration in an array, but I am looking for a better method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use toArray() instead toJS():

```js
const map1 = Immutable.Map({a:1, b:2, c:3});

const myMap = map1.map((elem, index) => {
    return "Hello " + elem;
})

console.log(myMap.toArray());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.2/immutable.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the array by simply using [myMap.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/keys)

```
Array.from(myMap.keys());
```

Runnable code snippet for the same is as under:

```
const map1 = Immutable.Map({a:1, b:2, c:3});

const myMap = map1.map((elem, index) => {
    return "Hello " + elem;
})

console.log(Array.from(myMap.keys()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just providing a different flavor using reduce

```js
const map1 = Immutable.Map({a:1, b:2, c:3});

const myMap = map1.reduce((accumulator, value) => {
    accumulator.push("Hello" + value);
    return accumulator;
}, [])

console.log(myMap);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.2/immutable.js"></script>
```